# Unable to make Omnet 5.0 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, omnet++

I followed intructions at below links:

https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf and http://vikashmainanwal.blogspot.com.tr/2014/10/omnet-simulator-installation-steps-in.html .I'm getting these errors on Ubuntu 16.04:

> make MODE=release
>
> make[1]: Entering directory '/home/besglab/omnetpp-5.0'
>   ***** Configuration: MODE=release, TOOLCHAIN_NAME=gcc, LIB_SUFFIX=.so ****
>   ===== Checking environment =====
>   ===== Compiling utils ====
>
> make[2]: Entering directory '/home/besglab/omnetpp-5.0/src/utils'
>   Copying scripts to bin directory... /bin/sh: 1: cannot create
>   /home/besglab/.wishname: Permission denied
>
> Makefile:32: recipe for target 'all' failed
>
> make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/besglab/omnetpp-5.0/src/utils'
>   Makefile:100: recipe for target 'utils' failed
>
> make[1]: *** [utils] Error 2
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/besglab/omnetpp-5.0'
>
> Makefile:23: recipe for target 'allmodes' failed
>
> make: *** [allmodes] Error 2

Could you give me advices??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a permission problem either on your whole HOME directory, or just on the file .wishname (probably you ran the configure file as root before and the .wishname file remained).

Delete the .whichname file and try again.

`$ rm ~/.wishname`